# Flask and React App in single Docker Container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Good day SO,

I know this is bad practice and that I am supposed to have one App per container, but is there a way for me to have two services running concurrently in the same container, and how would I go about writing the Dockerfile for it?

My current Dockerfile for the Flask (Backend) App:

```
FROM python:3.6.9-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app/flask_backend

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/app"

COPY ./flask_backend ./

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD python3 app/webapp/app.py
```

My React (Frontend) Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.18.0-alpine as build

WORKDIR /app/react_frontend

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"

COPY ./react_frontend/package.json ./
COPY ./react_frontend/package-lock.json ./

RUN npm ci
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g
RUN npm install serve -g

COPY ./react_frontend ./

CMD ["serve", "-s", "build", "-l", "3000"]
```

My attempt to launch both apps within the same Docker Container was to merge the two Dockerfiles, but the resulting container does not have the data from the first Dockerfile, and I am unsure how to proceed.

My merged Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.9-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app/flask_backend

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/app"

COPY ./flask_backend ./

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD python3 app/webapp/app.py

FROM node:12.18.0-alpine as build

WORKDIR /app/react_frontend

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"

COPY ./react_frontend/package.json ./
COPY ./react_frontend/package-lock.json ./

RUN npm ci
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g
RUN npm install serve -g

COPY ./react_frontend ./

CMD ["serve", "-s", "build", "-l", "3000"]
```

I am a beginner in using Docker, and hence I forsee that there will be several problems, such as communications between the two apps (Backend uses port 5000), using this method. Any guidiance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Indeed it is not the way it should work, but you can play around. **1)** Use a single Alpine or Ubuntu or any other OS image, install required dependencies like python and nodejs. **2)** Copy your source code in respective directories under the container. **3)** Create a shell script which would run both python and nodejs app in background. **4)** Execute the script with **ENTRYPOINT** command. Conceptually this should work, **BUT DON'T DO THIS WAY**. **USE Docker Compose**

Comment: Is it possible to achieve multiple services in a single docker container via docker-compose? and if so, are there any examples i could follow? Thanks!

Comment: Read through the official documentation of docker-compose. Related sample: https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A React application doesn't usually have a server *per se* (development-only Docker setups aside).  Instead, you run a tool like Webpack to compile it down to static files, which you can then serve to the browser, which then runs them.

On your host system you'd run something like

```
yarn build
```

which produces a `dist` directory; then you'd copy this into your Flask [static directory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/static/).

If you do this entirely ahead-of-time, then you can run your application out of a Python virtual environment, which will be a much easier development and test setup, and the Dockerfile you show won't change.

If you want to build this entirely in Docker (for example to take advantage of a more Docker-native automated build system) a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) matches well here.  You can use a first stage to build the front-end application, and then `COPY` that into the final application in the second stage.  That looks roughly like:

```sh
FROM node:12.18.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app/react_frontend
COPY ./react_frontend/package.json ./
COPY ./react_frontend/package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY ./react_frontend ./
RUN npm run build

FROM python:3.6.9-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app/flask_backend
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/app"

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./flask_backend ./
COPY --from=build /app/react_frontend/dist/ ./static/

CMD python3 app/webapp/app.py
```

This approach is not compatible with setups that overwrite Docker image contents using bind mounts.  A non-Docker host Node and Python setup will be a much easier development environment, and for this particular setup isn't likely to be substantially different from the Docker setup.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I will try and get it to work :) do you have any idea how do I run 'npm start' after i copy the build over to the python image?

Comment: You don't.  Once you have the `dist` tree you just serve it as static files; there's no separate server process to run.

Comment: I ran npm run build but instead of a /dist directory, a /build directory was created instead, do I do the COPY on the new /build dir?

Comment: It should be a directory with one or two HTML files and one or two Javascript files.  Those are the files you need two copy.

Comment: i managed to do a static deployment, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Does copying the dist/ from build affect the backend code at all in terms of how it is started?

Comment: @DavidMaze  I am also able to use multistage build and get static directory. Now does my UI port/endpoint need change due to this? I am not getting UI pulled up as it was with separate builds earlier